# ProgrammingError at / ORDER BY "id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...logapp_article.userid=blogapp_useradd.uname ORDER BY id DESC

Tags: django, sqlite, heroku

**Exception Value:**
ORDER BY "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...logapp_article.userid=blogapp_useradd.uname ORDER BY id DESC

**Error location from views.py**

def Index(request):

```
ad1 = ads.objects.raw("select * from blogapp_ads order by id desc limit 1")
ad2 = ads.objects.raw("select * from blogapp_ads order by id desc limit 1 offset 1")
ad34 = ads.objects.raw("select * from blogapp_ads order by id desc limit 2 offset 2")
ob1 = news.objects.raw("select * from blogapp_news order by id desc limit 5")
obb = article.objects.raw(
    "select * from blogapp_article inner join blogapp_useradd on blogapp_article.userid=blogapp_useradd.uname ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 14")
obj = article.objects.raw(
    "select * from blogapp_article inner join blogapp_useradd on blogapp_article.userid=blogapp_useradd.uname ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5")
ob = article.objects.raw(
    "select * from blogapp_article inner join blogapp_useradd on blogapp_article.userid=blogapp_useradd.uname ORDER BY id DESC")
return render(request, 'Guest/Index.html', context={'data9':obb, 'data3': ob1,'data1': ob, 'data2':obj, 'time': now,'data4':ad1,'data5':ad2,'data6':ad34})
```

Comment: Qualify the column `id` with the table name, like  `blogapp_article.id` or `blogapp_useradd.id`

Comment: Is there a reason why you make raw queries here? All the above queries can be perfectly done (in a shorter manner) with the Django ORM.

Answer (score 0):

Without visibility into the tables, I'm assuming "id" exists as an attribute in both of the tables you are joining. Try changing your join statement to:

```
ob = article.objects.raw(
    "select * from blogapp_article as a inner join blogapp_useradd as b on a.userid=b.uname ORDER BY a.id DESC")
```

Comment: Thank you,This code will remove my error. Try this if similar error is occurred